# git - how to Sync 2 remote repos without fetch/pull to local

Tags: git

### Reason/Usercase

The repo is too large under a VPN which is way too slow, I want to overwrite origin/master with upstream/master without fetching/pulling down to my local env.

### What I want

Is there any git command that can do something like this:

```bash
# to push branch upstream/master to origin/master forcely
git push -f upstream/master origin/master
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to ssh into the target server machine and give Git commands there?

Comment: You could do a shallow clone and only pull the history from origin that is not already in upstream.

Comment: @matt Not able to, thanks.

Comment: @Chronial you mean I still need to pull into my local env?

Comment: @ChenTian Yes, but only the commits that are actually different between the repos

Comment: @Chronial Sorry, I learned the `shallow clone` just now, and I don't see any difference with `git fetch upstream master ;  git reset --hard upstream/master ; git push -f -u origin master`.

Comment: If you cannot give Git commands on either server then you must work locally; you cannot avoid fetching/cloning to your local and then pushing from your local.

Answer (score 1):

If :

1. serverA (resp. serverB) can reach serverB (resp. serverA) through ssh,
2. you can log into serverA (resp. serverB) as the user who owns the git repo locally.

then you can ssh to that server and push to other server / pull from the other server :

```
# a convenient way is to create a named remote, and then fetch or pull :
git remote add upstream <ssh url to other git repo>

git fetch upstream main
# inspect your repo ...
git reset --hard upstream/main

# or :

git push --force upstream main:main
```

You can actually do it without changing the configuration :

```
git fetch <ssh url from other repo> main
# you inspect the state of your repo using 'git log', the branch you just
# fetched can be accessed through FETCH_HEAD
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD

# or :

git push --force <ssh url from other repo> main
```

If you can, I would suggest to log into the fetching server, as you can inspect and revert more freely your actions locally.

---

Emphasis on "user who owns the repo locally" :

since your actions will lead to writing files in the local `.git/` directory, you don't want to mess with the access rights within that directory.

In particular : if you act as `root`, you could end up having files owned by `root` under `.git/`, which would make later regular actions fail randomly because they can't modify target files.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot log into either remote upstream or origin, cuz I am just a developer of a big company, who forked the project from `upstream` to my own developing repo `origin`. And I'm afraid both the official `upstream` and all other `origin`s(owned by my workmates) are hosted on the same Server, you know, something like `https://company-github-host/department-code/repo-name` for `upstream`, and `https://company-github-host/my-employee-id/repo-name` for `origin`.

Comment: ok. You mention "github" : are you talking about private repositories hosted on github.com ? or does your company have its own gitlab instance running on one of its servers ?

Comment: (if it is a local gitlab instance) can you log into any machine (through your VPN) that would be on the same local network as this gitlab server ? If yes : from that machine you can clone `repoA` and push to `repoB`.

Comment: Answer1: the latter. It's an on-prem gitlab. Answer2: well, this should be a `Workaround`, instead of a `Answer`/`Solution`. Thank your for your answer, they are helpful!